# unable to get the value of node with position

Tags: xslt

I've an XML where there are 10 `phrase` nodes.

I'm trying to get the second phrase using the below XSLT.

```
<xsl:value-of select="document(concat('C:\Users\u0138039\Desktop\Proview\Files\','MCPV1_
ORD_34.XML'))/chapter//phrase[2]"/>
```

to my surprise this is not working.

and when i use the below.

```
<xsl:value-of select="document(concat('C:\Users\u0138039\Desktop\Proview\Files\','MCPV1_
ORD_34.XML'))/chapter//phrase"/>
```

**Input XML:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<index>
  <secondaryie>certification, 34/12</secondaryie>
 </index>
```

**title.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<entry>
  <file name="MCPV1_ORD_30.xml"/>
  <file name="MCPV1_ORD_31.xml"/>
  <file name="MCPV1_ORD_32.xml"/>
  <file name="MCPV1_ORD_33.xml"/>
  <file name="MCPV1_ORD_34.xml"/>
  <file name="MCPV1_ORD_35.xml"/>
</entry>
```

**Chapter 34.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<chapter num="34">
  <section level="sect1" number-type="manual" num="nonum">
    <para>
      <phrase>34/0/2</phrase>
    </para>
  </section>
  <section level="sect1" number-type="manual" num="nonum">
    <para>
      <phrase>34/0/3</phrase>
    </para>
  </section>
  <section level="sect1" number-type="manual" num="nonum">
    <para>
      <phrase>34/1</phrase>
    </para>
    <para>
      <phrase>34/1/1</phrase>
    </para>
  </section>
</chapter>
```

**XSLT:**

```
<xsl:template match="index">
  <div class="index">
    <xsl:apply-templates/>
  </div>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="secondaryie">
  <div class="secondaryie">
    <xsl:apply-templates/>
  </div>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="text()">
  <xsl:analyze-string select="." regex="([\w]+)/([\w]+)">
    <xsl:matching-substring>
      <xsl:variable name="prent">
        <xsl:for-each select="document('C:\Users\u0138039\Desktop\Proview\Files\title.xml')/entry/file">
          <xsl:value-of select="document(concat('C:\Users\u0138039\Desktop\Proview\Files\',./@name))/chapter[//phrase=.]/@num"/>
        </xsl:for-each>
      </xsl:variable>
      <a href="{$prent}">
        <xsl:value-of select="."/>
      </a>
    </xsl:matching-substring>
    <xsl:non-matching-substring>
      <xsl:value-of select="."/>
    </xsl:non-matching-substring>
  </xsl:analyze-string>
</xsl:template>
```

process is i run the Input XML with XSLT and it will loop through title.xml and then match the regex with the `phrase` present inside the documents(here i took 34 for reference), and it should print the chapter value.

In my XML `34/12` is present so it should print `<a href="34"/>` where as in my output it is showing `<a href=""/>`

Can someone please let me know, how can i fix it and why the data is not getting pulled in first case.

Thanks

Comment: "*to my surprise this is not working.*" What do you mean "not working"? Please post a **reproducible** example, including a sample XML input.

Comment: This is throwing null, there is no output

Comment: Can you post your xml that is loaded via document function

Comment: Hi @michael.hor257k, sorry for the delay, i posted the sample XML with XSLT and current and expected output

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of this

```
<xsl:value-of select="document(concat('C:\Users\u0138039\Desktop\Proview\Files\','MCPV1_
ORD_34.XML'))/chapter//phrase[2]"/>
```

Try this out:

```
<xsl:value-of select="(document(concat(C:\Users\u0138039\Desktop\Proview\Files\','MCPV1_ORD_34.XML'))/chapter//phrase)[2]"/>
```

You will get the second node. For your 34.xml I got the node with this value '34/0/3'

Comment: This is working, I'm sorry the actual requirement is to match the number in `input.xml`, with the phrase present in `Chapter` by looping through title.xml

Comment: If the answer is working then don't forget to accept the answer